# restrict ssh reverse portforwarding per user

Tags: ssh-tunnel, port-forwarding

I have a server that needs to accept incoming ssh connections with portforwarding. The incoming clients request a port forward from a port on the server to a port locally. They authenticate using a public/private key. So: on the client end `-R 40001:localhost:8443` is used to enable the server to connect to its own port 40001 and access an application on the client's port 8443.

How do I restrict the server so that this specific user can only forward port 40001 and no other port? I've looked at `permitopen`, but it seems to work only for forward, not reverse tunnels.